# Invoking rowGroup after the datatable is rendered completely

Tags: datatable, datatables

I have the following code that does row grouping as well as the average of the salary:

[Link to JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/bishalgautam/yc73vead/6/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
    order: [
      [2, 'asc']
    ],
    rowsGroup: [2],
    rowGroup: {
      startRender: null,
      endRender: function(rows, group) {

        var salaryAvg = rows
          .data()
          .pluck(5)
          .reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b.replace(/[^\d]/g, '') * 1;
          }, 0) / rows.count();
        salaryAvg = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '$').display(salaryAvg);

        var ageAvg = rows
          .data()
          .pluck(3)
          .reduce(function(a, b) {
            return a + b * 1;
          }, 0) / rows.count();
        console.log(salaryAvg);
        console.log(ageAvg);
        return $('<tr/>')
          .append('<td colspan="3">Averages for ' + group + '</td>')
          .append('<td>' + ageAvg.toFixed(0) + '</td>')
          .append('<td/>')
          .append('<td>' + salaryAvg + '</td>');
      },
      dataSrc: 2
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.4/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.4/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup/v1.0.0/dataTables.rowsGroup.js"></script>


<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Garrett Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Ashton Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Airi Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2012/08/06</td>
      <td>$137,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>55</td>
      <td>2010/10/14</td>
      <td>$327,900</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>39</td>
      <td>2009/09/15</td>
      <td>$205,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sonya Frost</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2008/12/13</td>
      <td>$103,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jena Gaines</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2008/12/19</td>
      <td>$90,560</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
      <td>Support Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2013/03/03</td>
      <td>$342,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Charde Marshall</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>36</td>
      <td>2008/10/16</td>
      <td>$470,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
      <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2012/12/18</td>
      <td>$313,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>19</td>
      <td>2010/03/17</td>
      <td>$385,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Silva</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2012/11/27</td>
      <td>$198,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Paul Byrd</td>
      <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2010/06/09</td>
      <td>$725,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gloria Little</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>59</td>
      <td>2009/04/10</td>
      <td>$237,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bradley Greer</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2012/10/13</td>
      <td>$132,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Dai Rios</td>
      <td>Personnel Lead</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>35</td>
      <td>2012/09/26</td>
      <td>$217,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
      <td>Development Lead</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2011/09/03</td>
      <td>$345,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Yuri Berry</td>
      <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>40</td>
      <td>2009/06/25</td>
      <td>$675,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Caesar Vance</td>
      <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2011/12/12</td>
      <td>$106,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Doris Wilder</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>23</td>
      <td>2010/09/20</td>
      <td>$85,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
      <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/10/09</td>
      <td>$1,200,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>42</td>
      <td>2010/12/22</td>
      <td>$92,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2010/11/14</td>
      <td>$357,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>2011/06/07</td>
      <td>$206,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Fiona Green</td>
      <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>48</td>
      <td>2010/03/11</td>
      <td>$850,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shou Itou</td>
      <td>Regional Marketing</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>20</td>
      <td>2011/08/14</td>
      <td>$163,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michelle House</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>Sidney</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2011/06/02</td>
      <td>$95,400</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Suki Burks</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>53</td>
      <td>2009/10/22</td>
      <td>$114,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
      <td>Technical Author</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/05/07</td>
      <td>$145,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
      <td>Team Leader</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2008/10/26</td>
      <td>$235,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Martena Mccray</td>
      <td>Post-Sales support</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/03/09</td>
      <td>$324,050</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Unity Butler</td>
      <td>Marketing Designer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/12/09</td>
      <td>$85,675</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/12/16</td>
      <td>$164,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
      <td>Secretary</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>41</td>
      <td>2010/02/12</td>
      <td>$109,850</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
      <td>Financial Controller</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>62</td>
      <td>2009/02/14</td>
      <td>$452,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
      <td>Office Manager</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2008/12/11</td>
      <td>$136,200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
      <td>Director</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>65</td>
      <td>2008/09/26</td>
      <td>$645,750</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Olivia Liang</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2011/02/03</td>
      <td>$234,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruno Nash</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>38</td>
      <td>2011/05/03</td>
      <td>$163,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>37</td>
      <td>2009/08/19</td>
      <td>$139,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Thor Walton</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2013/08/11</td>
      <td>$98,540</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Finn Camacho</td>
      <td>Support Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2009/07/07</td>
      <td>$87,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
      <td>Data Coordinator</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>64</td>
      <td>2012/04/09</td>
      <td>$138,575</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2010/01/04</td>
      <td>$125,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
      <td>Software Engineer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>56</td>
      <td>2012/06/01</td>
      <td>$115,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
      <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>43</td>
      <td>2013/02/01</td>
      <td>$75,650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Cara Stevens</td>
      <td>Sales Assistant</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>46</td>
      <td>2011/12/06</td>
      <td>$145,600</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Hermione Butler</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>47</td>
      <td>2011/03/21</td>
      <td>$356,250</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Lael Greer</td>
      <td>Systems Administrator</td>
      <td>London</td>
      <td>21</td>
      <td>2009/02/27</td>
      <td>$103,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
      <td>Developer</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>30</td>
      <td>2010/07/14</td>
      <td>$86,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Shad Decker</td>
      <td>Regional Director</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>51</td>
      <td>2008/11/13</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Michael Bruce</td>
      <td>Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Singapore</td>
      <td>29</td>
      <td>2011/06/27</td>
      <td>$183,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Donna Snider</td>
      <td>Customer Support</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>27</td>
      <td>2011/01/25</td>
      <td>$112,000</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Start date</th>
      <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

Now when i use ajax request in the same code the group is *undefined*. **And the other part of the group code doesn't work.** A little research and i found that it might have happened because of ajax request not completely rendered in the table and the endRender might not have known about the group.

So my question is how can i implement the endRender code after ajax request is completely rendered in the datatable so that endRender can know about the rowGroup. Or is there any way to achieve the solution to my problem?

**UPDATED:**

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: false babel: false -->
```

**Updated Code for ajax request also**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/zzaca',
        order: [[2, 'asc']],        
        columns: [           
            { data: 'name' },
            { data: 'position' },
            { data: 'office' },
            { data: 'extn' },
            { data: 'start_date' },
            { data: 'salary' }
        ],
        rowsGroup:[2],
        rowGroup: {
            startRender: null,
            endRender: function ( rows, group ) {
                    
                var salaryAvg = rows
                    .data()
                    .pluck(5)
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return a + b;
                    }, 0) / rows.count();
                salaryAvg = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '$').display( salaryAvg );
 
                var ageAvg = rows
                    .data()
                    .pluck(3)
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return a + b*1;
                    }, 0) / rows.count();
            console.log(salaryAvg);
            console.log(ageAvg);
                return $('<tr/>')
                    .append( '<td colspan="3">Averages for '+group+'</td>' )
                    .append( '<td>'+ageAvg.toFixed(0)+'</td>' )
                    .append( '<td/>' )
                    .append( '<td>'+salaryAvg+'</td>' );
            },
            dataSrc: 2
        }
    } );
} );
```

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.4/js/dataTables.rowGroup.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/rowgroup/1.0.4/css/rowGroup.dataTables.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/ashl1/datatables-rowsgroup/v1.0.0/dataTables.rowsGroup.js"></script>
    <script src="abcd.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
               
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
            
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: your fiddle is blank

Comment: please check again

Comment: Ok. So you have grouped row with Office and getting avg of all salary in a Office group.  Group seems to working fine .. Whats issue ??

Comment: Please re-read my question, the same code isn't working for ajax request.

Comment: Can you add code ..  how you are doing ajax call in Datatable...  As in Question and Fiddle ...  Both have static Data ....

Comment: please check the added code for ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few changes when you deal with ajax instead of Array.

```
dataSrc: 'office',
```

`datasrc` has to be attr which you are grouping with. Here `office`

```
var salaryAvg = rows
    .data()
    .reduce( function (a, b) {
        return a + b.salary.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')*1;
    }, 0) / rows.count();
```

This is not an array so pluck() will not work instead you need to get attr from JSON like this `b.office`

```
var ageAvg = rows
    .data()
    .reduce( function (a, b) {
        return a + b.extn*1;
    }, 0) / rows.count();
```

Same thing for `extn` attr

Full Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {

    ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/zzaca',
    order: [[2, 'asc']],        
    columns: [           
        { data: 'name' },
        { data: 'position' },
        { data: 'office' },
        { data: 'extn' },
        { data: 'start_date' },
        { data: 'salary' }
    ],
    rowsGroup:[2],
    rowGroup: {
        dataSrc: 'office',
        startRender: null,
        endRender: function ( rows, group ) {
            var salaryAvg = rows
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return a + b.salary.replace(/[^\d]/g, '')*1;
                }, 0) / rows.count();

            salaryAvg = $.fn.dataTable.render.number(',', '.', 0, '$').display( salaryAvg );


            var ageAvg = rows
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return a + b.extn*1;
                }, 0) / rows.count();

            return $('<tr/>')
                .append( '<td colspan="3">Averages for '+group+'</td>' )
                .append( '<td>'+ageAvg.toFixed(0)+'</td>' )
                .append( '<td/>' )
                .append( '<td>'+salaryAvg+'</td>' );
        },

    }
    } );
} );
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yc73vead/49/)

**Edit 1:**

Answering : why datasrc with attr works but not with other case?

In first case where Data is in Array form like this

```
var a = [2, "hello", "test", "$22500"]
```

you will get value using its index

In case of ajax your Object type is JSON something like this

```
var a = {  "name" : "test", "value" : "$22055"}
```

Now you can't read this by index. You can access it using attr like this

```
a.name // test
```

Comment: would you like to explain why datasrc with attr works but not with other case? I will upvote if you explain it.